# How do I make an ObjectWriter that uses both filters and pretty print?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Jackson offers the methods:

```
ObjectWriter ObjectMapper.writer(FilterProvider)
ObjectWriter ObjectMapper.writer(PrettyPrinter)
ObjectWriter ObjectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
```

But I want to use both pretty printing and a custom FilterProvider in my writer. How do I get a writer that uses both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take still configure this on the `ObjectWriter` instance returned by any of the `ObjectMapper.write()` method:

```
ObjectWriter objectWriter = ObjectMapper.writer(yourFilterProvider).withPrettyPrinter(yourPrettyPrinter); 
// or
ObjectWriter objectWriter = ObjectMapper.writer(yourPrettyPrinter).withFilters(yourPrettyPrinter);
```

See the [ObjectWriter class](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.2/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectWriter.html) for more information

Comment: In Jackson 2, the syntax would be: ObjectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().with(yourFilterProvider);